# How to catch form submit method With SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, forms, try-catch, laravel-blade, sweetalert2

my javascript knowledge is also very poor so please help.
I'm trying to secure the users page and add confirm dialog to delete.
But I don't know how to catch the submit methods.
I use confirm from sweetalert2,
but unfortunately the form method runs without clicking on any of the buttons.

So my question is how to modify the code?

```
<form action="{{ route('users.destroy', ['user' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id()]) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button id="comfirm-delete" class="btn btn-danger">User Delete</button>
</form>


<script>
    $(function () {
      'use strict';

      var comfirmDelete = $('#comfirm-delete');

      if (comfirmDelete.length) {
        comfirmDelete.on('click', function() {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
            customClass: {
              confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
              cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-danger ml-1'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false
          }).then(function(result) {
            if (result.value) {
              Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Deleted!',
                text: '',
                customClass: {
                  confirmButton: 'btn btn-success'
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }

    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how

If you have more than one form, you need a class and to cache the form instead of using `$('#myForm')`

```js
$(function() {
  const $myForm = $('#myForm')
    .on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
          cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-danger ml-1'
        },
        buttonsStyling: false
      }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.value) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Deleted!',
            text: '',
            customClass: {
              confirmButton: 'btn btn-success'
            }
          });
          setTimeout(function() {
            $myForm[0].submit()
          }, 2000); // submit the DOM form
        }
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.15.5/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="myForm">
  <button class="confirm-delete btn btn-danger">User Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: **$('#myForm')** can be put in a **var** to prevent using selector more than once . like  `me= this` and then `me.submit()`

Comment: @LittleElite Ok. Done

Answer (score 0):

If I can see one of the mistakes is,
I watched the button instead of the form?